# img vertical align is not working inside a colorbox

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've used the line-height property in the parent and the vertical-align in the child:

```
<div style="height:500px; line-height:500px">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" />
</div>
```

It Works inside the body tag but when I try to put that content inside a colorbox the image aligns to the top, Is there some restriction of this rule inside absolute positioned elements, floated elements or something???

If anyone knows a better way to center an image vertically (not with top:50%) I'd appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: Use some developer tools to see what the calculated/computed CSS is at that point. You may have another style elsewhere that the browser decides has higher precedence causing an override. Firebug and the like will tell you where a particular style directive comes from, and which one is actually in effect.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and after comparing every single style I deleted de colobox css but it didn't solve the problem so I think it should be something related whith the HTML. At the end I changed the DOCTYPE from transitional to RDFa and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *display: table-cell* but you will have to put another div wrapping the image at this way:

```
<div style="display: table-row; height: 500px;">
 <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
  <img src="someimage.jpg"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After comparing every single style (computed and not) I deleted de colobox css but it didn't solve the problem so I think it should be something related whith the HTML. At the end I changed the DOCTYPE from transitional to RDFa and it worked!!